# ClearButtonVisibility property doesn't work inside a frame in .net maui

Tags: c#, maui, cleartext

I put the ClearButtonVisibility in an entry and the entry inside a fame and the Clear Button Visibility doesn't work, how do i make it work

int the xaml code i have this:

```
<Frame Margin="35,0,35,0" Padding="0">
    <Entry Placeholder="This is a freaky entry"
           ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing"/>
</Frame>
```

Comment: As a sanity check, if your remove the frame, it works as expected? You clicked on Entry, to give it focus?

Answer (score 0):

The ClearButtonVisibility property can be used to control whether an Entry displays a clear button. You can set it to WhileEditing, that indicates a clear button will be displayed in the Entry, while it has focus and text.

However, several Github issues for **ClearButtonVisibility** could be found.

[Entry ClearButton does not clear the text? #9954](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9954)

[ClearButtonVisibility is not working #6360](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/6360)

You could follow this thread. Referring to the above thread, i think you could update your Visual Studio. Or remove Padding in VerticalStackLayout as ismasanchez said.

For more info, you could refer to [.NET MAUI Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry).